# SQL Server Dynamic Column's

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-columns

I want to create an app like asana which has a dynamic column

Add Field option in ASANA

[image]

I don't want to use NO-SQL.

The idea is like in mariadb [dynamic-columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns)

```
create table assets (
  item_name varchar(32) primary key, -- A common attribute for all items
  dynamic_cols  blob  -- Dynamic columns will be stored here
);
```

```
INSERT INTO assets VALUES 
  ('MariaDB T-shirt', COLUMN_CREATE('color', 'blue', 'size', 'XL'));
INSERT INTO assets VALUES
  ('Thinkpad Laptop', COLUMN_CREATE('color', 'black', 'price', 500));
```

```
SELECT item_name, COLUMN_GET(dynamic_cols, 'color' as char) AS color FROM assets;
+-----------------+-------+
| item_name       | color |
+-----------------+-------+
| MariaDB T-shirt | blue  |
| Thinkpad Laptop | black |
+-----------------+-------+
```

I also have another idea to create a dynamic table, but I'm hesitant to implement because, I'm not that expert in SQL Server.
I'm afraid that this idea might take a long trip in the database.
The idea goes like below

```
create table assets_columns (
  id integer primary key,
  column_name varchar(100)
);
```

```
create table assets_values (
  id integer primary key,
  column_name varchar(100),
  column_value varchar(100),
);
```

What do you think about my idea?
Do you have another idea?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing an EAV design . These *rarely* work well in a RDBMS; they break the fundamental principles of normalisation.

Comment: Also, forcing yourself down a dynamic solution is a trap too; it'll make your data a nightmare to maintain and very easily introduces security flaws if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Larnu What would be your advice?

Comment: Use a normalised, and non-dynamic design.

Comment: I'm afraid non-dynamic design is not an option for me, but I will consider that advice as my last option. Thank you.

Comment: The advice depends entirely on the use case and the nature of your data. Do you have sparse columns? Do you have foreign key columns? Do you need to filter or sort on columns? What are your requirements in terms of size and speed?

Comment: sparse columns - never tried it, foreign key columns - yes, filter or sort on columns - yes, in terms of size and speed - not that fast but acceptable @RuudHelderman

Comment: *"I'm afraid non-dynamic design is not an option for me"* Then I would suggest not using an RDBMS if I am honest. You are in for a world of pain.

Comment: @Larnu  _"Then I would suggest not using an RDBMS"_ . This is also one of my options. But I like to pursue this using RDBMS.

Comment: Then, like I said, if you want to use an RDBMS you should be creating a normalised design. That is what an RDBMS excels are. Objects are well defined, with fixed definitions. A single value in a specific row and column represents a single atomic value.

Comment: You can try using json to store data in the sql server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Larnu I get your point. I think I'm going to use mongodb.

Comment: @KhertGeverola, my life since I began in this industry. Before modern approaches like JSON or dynamic columns, I wrote at least six systems based on Data/Meta-Data ERD, sort of your another idea, but with more elegance :-) Either Data/Meta-Data, JSON, or Dynamic approaches bumps at the very same challenge: retrieving data. A lesson I learned after these years and systems: before devising the data layer, architecture, try to anticipate how the data will be fetched, queried, and aggregated, how the platform (C#, PHP) and framework (EF/OleDB, PDO/Laravel) will help or will impede the tasks ahead.